# last line of batch file is not read until batch file is closed

Tags: c#, process

I have a code that executes a bat file and outputs the output of the bat file in the console of my c# application. But when I run the application the last file of the bat file isn't read until the bat file is closed

I've did some research and there were some different ways to output it to the c# console, but they all had the same problem

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Directory.GetFiles(string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Downloads", Environment.UserName), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length <= 2)
            {
                Process p = new Process();

                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                //p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Downloads\test.bat", Environment.UserName);
                p.OutputDataReceived += CaptureOutput;
                p.Start();
                p.BeginOutputReadLine();

                //while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                //{
                //    string line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                //    Console.WriteLine(line);
                //    //Console.WriteLine("--kl--");
                //}
            }   
        }
        static void CaptureOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
```

and the content of the test.bat file:

```
@echo off
timeout 10
echo YouCanCloseNow
pause
```

and the console prints

```
Waiting for 10 seconds, press a key to continue ... 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
YouCanCloseNow
```

but doesn't print

```
Press any key to continue . . .
```

until the cmd window is closed

So as I said I want the `Press any key to continue . . .` printed in the console without me needing to close the cmd file

Comment: How do you execute the program? F5 or Ctrl+F5?

Comment: You have a flush issue.  You can run the bat file with the /k option which keeps the window open after the bat terminates.  From cmd.exe try help to see more info.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I use visual studio and just hit the "Start" Button

Comment: @jdweng Hi, I forgot to mention that the first line comes after 10 seconds, wich means that its only outputted in the console after the second line should've been outputted if you get you get what I mean

Comment: I do.  That is why I'm suggesting running the bat file using the /K option.  This way the bat window stays open until you close it when the Process class is terminated.  You will probably have to kill the window by getting the process id.

Comment: @jdweng You mean change it to `p.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Downloads\test.bat /K", Environment.UserName);`?

Comment: You need to use c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K .......

Comment: @jdweng `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'`

Comment: Use windows Explorer to check path of cmd.exe.  It could be the path of the bat that is also wrong.

Comment: The file name is cmd.exe and you need to use arguments string.Format(@"/K C:\Users\{0}\Downloads\test.bat", Environment.UserName); See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8